# Making a list of strings with 2 parameters. Python 3.3

Tags: python, string, list

So lets say I have a sentence read from a file:

```
hello what is your name
my name is david
```

I am trying to make a list of strings from this so it looks like:

```
['hello','what','is','your','name','my','name','is','david']
```

The main problem is when I use the split option, I can only specify one parameter to split the string by.

I end up with either

```
['hello what is your name','my name is david']
```

When splitting by '\n'

OR

```
['hello','what','is','your','name\n','my','name','is','david\n']
```

When splitting by 'spacebar'.

Is there a way I can combine both these parameters to produce the list of strings above these two?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't specify any parameter: split()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `text.split()`, it will split the string by space, tab, and new line.

```
text = """hello what is your name
my name is david"""
print text.split()

#output: ['hello', 'what', 'is', 'your', 'name', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'david']
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It turns out the problem all along was that I used text.split(' ') to specify spacebar. But text.split() splits everything. I had a feeling the answer I needed was dead simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
phrase = """hello what is your name
my name is david"""
l = [word.replace('\n', '') for word in phrase.split()]
```